# Linq OrderBy with an expression variable

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to figure out how to sort by a variable, not a string.
I believe I should be able to represent `x => x.SomeProperty` and save that to a variable and pass it into the `OrderBy` method but can't figure out what to use here.

```
SomeType sortExpr = null;
switch(sortByColumnName)
{
    case "Name":
        sortExpr = x => x.Name
        break;
    case "Age":
        sortExpr = x => x.Age
        break;
    case "OtherThing":
        sortExpr = x => x.OtherReference.Name
        break;
}

if (sortDirection == "asc")
    query = query.OrderBy(sortExpr);
else
    query = query.OrderByDescending(sortExpr);
```

Comment: `OrderBy` accepts `Func<TSource,TKey> keySelector`

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski depends whether `query` is `IEnumerable` or `IQueryable`. The latter requires an `Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already said, `OrderBy` accepts `Func<TSource,TKey> keySelector` as its argument so `sortExpr` should e of that type, where `TSource` is object, which is stored in collection you want to sort, let's say of `User` class. `TKey` is type of property you want to sort by, since this can be of arbitrary type, you can make it `object`, as this type parameter is covariant.

So declare like

```
Func<User, object> sortExpr;
```

and rest code can stay as it is.

**EDIT**

If you are using `IQueryable<TSource>.OrderBy` version, which requires `Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>>`, then you just need to delare the variable as:

```
Expression<Func<User, object>> sortExpr;
```

Comment: Depends whether `query` is `IEnumerable<TSource>` or `IQueryable<TSource>`. The latter requires an `Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>>`.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Thanks, included that.

Comment: `Expression<Func<User, object>> sortExpr;` is what I was looking for, ty!